# How to update different rows of two columns with variables which represent the id of the other row using mysqli and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I'm not very experienced with SQL in general and I'm wondering how to combine these two separate update strings using the same variables:

```
$queryA = 'UPDATE table SET redirectsToId  ='.$redirectId.' WHERE id='.$id;    
$queryB = 'UPDATE table SET redirectFromId ='.$id.'         WHERE id='.$redirectId;
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

EDIT: What is the most performant way to do so in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to.  In most databases, you can wrap the two statements in a single transaction so they take effect "simultaneously".

But, you can also do:

```
UPDATE table
    SET redirectsToId  = (CASE WHEN id = $id THEN $redirectId ELSE redirectsToId END),
        redirectsFromId = (CASE WHEN id = $id THEN redirectsFromId ELSE $id)
    WHERE id IN ($id, $redirectId);
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is very close to what I tried according to another solution on SO and wrongly thought it didn't work (but in the end it did).

"$query = 'UPDATE table SET redirectsToId = CASE id WHEN '.$id.' THEN '.$redirectId.' ELSE redirectsToId END,
redirectFromId = CASE id WHEN '.$redirectId.' THEN '.$id.' ELSE redirectFromId END
WHERE id in ('.$redirectId.', '.$id.')';"

Is there a difference in internal handling when I use "CASE id WHEN $id" instead of "CASE WHEN id = $id" as you suggested?

How can I wrap two statements into a single transaction?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to. Just keep them two separate updates.